# Prove that $r^n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $r>1$, then $r^n\to\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

> Write $r=1+c$, where $c=r-1>0$. Then for each positive integer $n$ we have
>   $$r^n=(1+c)^n>nc$$
>   Given $K>0$, take 
>   $$N= \text{least integer greater than }\frac{K} c.$$
>   Then $r^n>K$ for all $n\geq N$.

Can someone explain why $nc$ is being used? It seems so arbitrary.

Comment: This follows from [Bernoulli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 2):

$nc$ was used because it makes it easy to satisfy the inequality $r^n>K$, transformed to $nc>K$, with $n>\dfrac Kc$.

Without this simplification trick, you would need the more "sophisticated" $n>\dfrac{\log K}{\log r}$.

Answer (score 1):

$nc$ is used because it works. There's probably a lot of ways to prove that, whoever wrote that chose one way, that involved $nc$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know how $r^n$ behaves when $n \to \infty$, but you know how $nc$ behaves as $n \to \infty$.

So you try to use what you know: Since $r^n > nc$, and the latter $\to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, you can conclude that $r^n \to \infty$ also.

Nothing special about $nc$ except that it happens to work!